# rotate 3d pictures using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am starting working on a one page website which uses javascript extensively. The main purpose of this site is to promote my customers products. This website will include one product 3d image. When user clicks and drag then it should rotate according. Please see the link below. I need exactly the same kind of effect which is mentioned in following link

[click here for link](http://www.magictoolbox.com/magic360/)

How can I achieve this using javascript without using `magic 360`? Please give me some article or tutorial links as I searched but could not find any tutorials for this.

Comment: The rotating animation appears to have been created from a series of photographs instead of a 3D model. In this case, I suppose you could you the same method that you would use to rotate any other series of images.

Comment: There's really no other way to do that other than using pictures. At least not if you're trying to get it done this century and staying sane, as learning something like three.js or mapping 3D in canvas/svg takes forever.

Comment: Er. no it doesnt, ive only been learning three js for a couple of weeks ( im just slow) i could probably do this or something like it. its not hard once you properly understand 3d graphics and renderers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's some javascript I just threw together. Pick one of the pre-built libraries (for browser compatibility etc etc) but when you get a chance dig into what is actually happening. **note** I wrote this in the answer submit form so there may be syntax and other errors

```
<!-- an empty div to hold your images / frames -->
<div id="view3d"></div>
...
<script>
    (function() {

    // setup
    var viewer = document.getElementById("view3d");
    var name = "3d Boat";
    var frameUri = "/images/demo3d.#.jpg";
    var frameStart = 1;
    var frameEnd = 100;

    // setup the html IMG's
    for(var i=frameStart; i<=frameEnd; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = frameUri.replace("#", i);
        img.alt = name;
        img.style.display = "none";
        viewer.appendChild(img);
    }

    // persisted variables and events
    var that = this;
    this.rotateX = 0;
    this.isRotating = false;
    this.frames = viewer.getElementsByTagName("img");
    this.frameIdx = 0;
    this.pixelsPerFrame = viewer.offsetWidth / (frames.length / 2);
    function rotateMouseUp() { isRotating = false; };
    function rotateMouseDown(event) { 
        mouseX = event.pageX;
        isRotating = true; 
    };
    function rotateMouseMove(event) {
        if(!this.isRotating) 
            return;
        var x = event.pageX;
        var delta = this.rotateX - x;
        if(delta >= this.pixelsPerFrame) {
            this.rotateX = x;
            this.frames[this.frameIdx].style.display = 'none';
            this.frameIdx = (this.frameIdx + parseInt(delta / pixelsPerFrame)) % this.frames.length;
            this.frames[this.frameIdx].style.display = '';
        }
    }
    viewer.onmousedown = rotateMouseDown.bind(that);
    viewer.onmouseup = rotateMouseUp.bind(that);
    viewer.onmousemove = rotateMouseMove.bind(that);

    // show the first image
    this.frames[this.frameIdx].style.display = '';

    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I Just wanted to ask a question. I am going through the same issue what kind of images should I upload to achieve this effect? Let's say I have a 3D model of a chair or a house. Do I export a Png of every iteration possible or is there a trick to bypass this? Thanks.

Comment: @ambaamba - this answer is 9 years old. If you already have a 3d model you'd be better off using a javascript 3d library, load the model and map mouse movement to model rotation

Answer (score 4):

There are ready jQuery plugins for this, for instance:

http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel

http://www.mathieusavard.info/threesixty/demo.html

Comment: Thank you! Of all the plugins people are recommending on this page, the Vostrel one was the only one I could get to work. And it's extremely customizable.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a GIF, or a Series of images. My (preferred but not easiest) way is to use THREE.js and WebGL you make the model in Sketchup or Collada, then put it into js, the code is reltively simple, and it gives you lighting effects too!

http://carvisualizer.plus360degrees.com/threejs/

This ^ is an example of what it can do.

Here is a quick demo I whipped up for you.

http://deepschool.kd.io/Pages/Experiments/ThreeJs/clickcontroltestone.htm

```
geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ 
        color: 0xffffff
    }); 
    cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); 
    scene.add(cube);
```

Replace *geometry* with your file, and you have a spinning model!
You can even sense clicks and hovers etc, and make the model Interactive!
See this for reference: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Using-SketchUp-Models

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Link is dead now, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.uize.com/examples/3d-rotation-viewer.html

Googled rotate 3d image javascript.  View Source and copy Uize.js

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but there is a new open source player for QTVR or magic 360 like object movies, called imgSpinner. Here is a link to [the project](https://github.com/pnykamp/imgSpinner)

Disclaimer - this is my project.